# Can I hide a :before or :after element if the original div has no content?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a div that says "Tags: Example 1, Example 2"

The css looks like this:

```
.tag {
    color: #bbb9b9;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.tag:before {
    content: 'Tags: ';
}

.tag:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

Now, if no tags show up at the Wordpress post, I also want to hide the text "Tags", but it is in a :before tag.

Is there a way to hide the :before element somehow? Since the :before element is never actually **empty**, I'm finding it hard to fix.

Comment: Works for me...if it's not actually "empty" then what is actually in it? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EoBREK

Comment: Hmm, it does. It's something with my wordpress plugin generating a &nbsp; when there's nothing there. This will be annoying to fix... thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

The :empty pseudo selector will select elements that contain either nothing or only an HTML comment.

It will only work if the div is completely empty or has comments.

```
<div></div>

<div><!-- Comment --></div>
```

If the div has space or tabulations, you will have to use the pseudo element :blank

```
<div> </div>
<!-- Notice that inside this div there is a blank space -->

<div>
  <!-- Comment-->
</div>
```

I think maybe this is what might happen. Although there is no content, the div may have some space or tabulation. If this doesn't help, it would be nice to have an example of the html code when it's theoretically empty.